# How is schema version used in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a migration with a timestamp older than the current timestamp in db/schema.rb, how come when I run rake db:migrate it is still run?

What is the purpose of db/schema.rb to have the version timestamp if I still can run migrations with a prior timestamp?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your migration timestamp is older than the current timestamp, the migration is still run.

The timestamp in db/schema prevents you to `rake db:migrate` already done migrations but it can't stop you to `rake db:migrate VERSION=xxxxxxx`

Comment: That's not correct. Without specifying VERSION I can still run migrations from previous timestamps.

Comment: How your db/schema can have a timestamp after an unrun migration ?

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, schema version was used to infer which migrations were (likely) run and which not. Nowadays, individual migrations are tracked separately, but schema version number isn't completely useless. The [docs say](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) (emphasis mine):

> db/schema.rb contains the current version number of the database. This **ensures conflicts** are going to happen in the case of a **merge** where **both branches touched the schema**. When that happens, solve conflicts manually, keeping the highest version number of the two.

Comment: The docs no longer say this. I can't think of a scenario where the schema itself wouldn't conflict and we would want the version number to raise a flag. Also it's not clear what to do in such a case other than simply resolve the version line by picking the higher number.

Answer (score 0):

Pick the *higher* number.

If you choose the lower version you might encounter a problem with `db:schema:load` (and tasks that use it).

While loading the schema, ActiveRecord will create all the structure defined in your schema file, but it will only insert `version` in `schema_migrations` up to the version in your file:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cac061e87e35decfa6936223cbb9039e28ea0982/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema.rb#L59

That means that despite your database having the correct schema, Rails might (depending on configuration) complain about migrations not having been run.